# reverting push'd git commit

Tags: git, merge, github, reset, revert

I've got a repo with two branches-- master and dev. I was working on the master branch and pulled, and got a message that the repo was up to date. I committed my changes, and pushed to the remote repo (on github). I got a message saying that some changes were rejected.

I then did a `git pull origin dev`, which apparently was the wrong thing to do-- since it merged the dev branch with my master, and like an idiot I didn't notice this until I'd already pushed again. So the last commit shows `Merge branch 'dev' of github.com:myuser/myrepo`.

I can get back to the last known good status on my local repo by doing a `git reset --hard [sha]`, with [sha] being the commit before the merge (though I'm not sure how to then make that change to the origin)-- or from what I've read I can also do a `git revert -m` and then commit/push that change.

Can anyone walk me through the "right way" to undo my merge, and restore both branches back to where they were prior to the merge?

Thanks-- if it matters this is a shared repo with only two developers, so it's not under heavy changes.

Edit to add: please talk to me as if I were a child. I have to admit this Git stuff still confuses me, so I'm far from a power user! Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `git reset --hard [sha]` will correct the branch on your local repository. To force this push to work, you can do a `git push origin +master:master`. The + sign will force the non-linear push to work.

If the other developers have already pulled you wrong commit, they will have to do a `git remote update`, then a `git reset --hard origin/master` (provided that they are on their master branch, and have not made any other commits.

Please use these commands with some caution :-). Good luck.

Comment: Risky but if there are just two developers, I think it's okay. Might make sense to backup atleast one copy of your repo before doing this just in case you mess up.

Comment: thanks felipefg-- looks like that worked perfectly! I appreciate the clear answer.

Comment: @Noufal: You don't really have to back up the whole repo - just create a branch at the old position of master.

Comment: Hello,I'm having the same problem. I want to cancel a merge that I pushed to the origin.

I already did `git reset --hard [sha]` but now I can't push to the origin, event with `-f` or `+recette:recette`.

Git is telling me :
`remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/recette (you should pull first)
To ssh://my-git-repo
 ! [remote rejected] recette -> recette (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://my-git-repo'`

Answer (score 2):

FelipeFG's answer works fine in a two-developer context where you can easily coordinate redoing the other guy's local repository, but you're actually better off using `git revert -m<parent id of mainline branch, 1 in this case> <commit ref>`. Then, when you're finished fixing it, just `git revert <revert commit>`, and `git merge dev` (it's important to revert your revert for this case, because otherwise `git merge dev` will not consider your old merge an ancestor, and this will lead to conflicts that have to be resolved).

The history will be ugly, but it will also support fast-forwarding, and you won't have to worry about some poor sap untangling a mess of local conflicts thanks to your history revision.

See http://opensource.apple.com/source/Git/Git-26/src/git-htmldocs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt for details.