# Git : how to revert one commit on master and push new changes

Tags: git, version-control

I have created one new branch `X`
Then I merge this branch with local `master` and push local `master` to `origin`
Then I do more changes on branch `X`

I would like to push these changes to `origin` but on `origin`, I would like that only previous commit message get appeared i.e. i would like merge new changes to last commit on `origin`.

Is it possible?

Comment: So basically, you want to erase the history? Why would you want that?

Comment: i would like to do it because i want that on remote repository only one commit log would show correspond to my changes

Comment: That still doesn't answer the *why* part. Anyway, it's not easy to do with basic Git - the remote and local repository are meant to be equal (hence the term cloning).

Answer (score 0):

See these other questions related to "how can I revert a previously pushed commit ?"

- [How can I undo a `git commit` locally and on a remote after `git push`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459080/how-can-i-remove-git-commit-after-git-push)
- [reverting push'd git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316438/reverting-pushd-git-commit)
- [Undo a Git commit after push using reverse patch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441902/undo-a-commit-after-push)

Since you pushed your commit, the action you want to do will change the remote branch history, and interfere with other users if they have pulled the `origin/master` branch.

Unless you have very strong reasons for removing that commit from `origin`'s history, just push your additional changes on top of the current `origin/master` branch.